# Extending object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, extend

I want to extend object in dojo similar to this from jQuery

```
var x = $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
```

Is this a solution

```
var x;
dojo.extend(x,obj1);
dojo.extend(x,obj2);
```

Or can I do

```
dojo.extend(x,obj1,obj2);
```

Is this available

```
var x = dojo.extend(obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement the same semantics as [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), you have to use [dojo.mixin()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/mixin.html#dojo-mixin) instead of [dojo.extend()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/extend.html) (which extends *prototypes*):

```
var x = dojo.mixin({}, obj1);
dojo.mixin(x, obj2);
```

**EDIT:** If you want to keep the code on one line, you can do:

```
var x = dojo.mixin(dojo.mixin({}, obj1), obj2);
```

Comment: does it take multiple arguments, is this possible `var x = dojo.mixin({}, obj1, obj2);

Comment: and one more query ... suppose i do `var x=dojo.mixin({}, dojo.mixin(obj1, obj2)); `, now obj1 will be altered.. am i right ?

Comment: @Boopathi, it only takes two arguments, and yes, `obj1` will indeed be altered in your second example.